# Incremental Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory

For this problem:

*Compute the conditional distribution of $B(s)$ given that $B(t_1) = A$ and $B(t_2) = B$,
where $0<t_1 <s<t_2$.*

I know the solution is normal with mean $A + \frac{(s-t_1)(B-A)}{t_2-t_1}$ and variance $\frac{(s-t_1)(t_2-s)}{t_2-t_1}$, but I'm not sure I fully follow the steps involved to arrive at this solution. It looks like we make use of the independent increments property; can someone help me understand the steps involved?

Comment: Though it's not necessarily the most "slick" solution, you can do it by knowing the multivariate distribution of $B(t_1),B(s)$ and $B(t_2)$, which is normal with mean $[0,0,0]^T$ and covariance matrix $\begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_1 & t_1 \\ t_1 & s & s \\ t_1 & s & t_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Meanwhile, $B(t_1)$ and $B(t_2)$ themselves are normal with mean $[0,0]^T$ and covariance matrix $\begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_1 \\ t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix}$. So you can compute $f(A,s,B)$ for the former and $f(A,B)$ for the latter and do the division.

Comment: The more slick approach is to essentially just write down an intuitive expression for a Brownian bridge and then prove that it behaves the way you want.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate a bit more on the Brownian bridge approach?

Comment: It's not very systematic, you just write, for the Brownian bridge from 0 to 0, $B(t)=W(t)-tW(1)$ where $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then you add a deterministic linear function to accommodate any discrepancy in the means and shift and rescale time (being careful that time rescaling with Brownian motion involves a square root) to go back to $[t_1,t_2]$. Then you go back and check that if you integrate over the possible values at the endpoints, you reconstruct standard BM.

Comment: Another non-systematic way I have seen is to just write down the SDE $dX_t=\frac{b-X_t}{T-t} + dB_t$ where $X_0=a,X_T=b$ and solve it. While it is intuitive to have $dX_t=f(t) (b-X_t) + dB_t$ for some $f(t)>0$, I find it not immediately obvious that $f(t)=\frac{1}{T-t}$.

Comment: Also in my first comment where I wrote $f(A,s,B)$ that should've been $f(A,x,B)$.

Comment: Sorry, I overcomplicated matters. I'm writing up a simple answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a Brownian bridge.

To analyze the distribution of the Brownian bridge at a particular intermediate time, consider the prior probability density to go from $A$ to $x$ to $B$, which is $f_{s-t_1}(x-A) f_{t_2-s}(B-x)$, where $f_t$ is the $N(0,t)$ PDF, i.e. $f_t(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-z^2/2t}$. This uses the independence of the increments.

Then consider the prior probability density to go from $A$ to $B$ overall, which is $f_{t_2-t_1}(B-A)$.

So the conditional PDF is the ratio of these:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(s-t_1)}} e^{-\frac{(x-A)^2}{2(s-t_1)}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t_2-s)}} e^{-\frac{(x-B)^2}{2(t_2-s)}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t_2-t_1)}} e^{-\frac{(B-A)^2}{2(t_2-t_1)}}}.$$

It's an ugly simplification job to see that this gives a normal with the mean and variance you expect.